# Find unique email id in each month in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset, formula

I have a dataset that contains email id, created date, and quantity. I want to find out how many NEW email id got created in a particular month. This is the Sample Dataset. How can we find the new email id for each month using excel formula.
I used this excel Formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF(Orders_Data!$G$2:$G$2442=Repeats_Summary_Copy!V3,1/COUNTIFS(Orders_Data!$G$2:$G$2442,Repeats_Summary_Copy!V3,Orders_Data!$B$2:$B$2442,Orders_Data!$B$2:$B$2442),0))`

to get the count. But I think its taking email id which are present in previous month also.
Data:

```
Email                        CreatedAt      Quantity
johnppibokh@email.com         2022-Sep-01       1
gopijipooj@email.com          2022-Sep-01       1
bibygog2016@email.com         2022-Oct-01       1
imiti4282@email.com           2022-Oct-01       2
godwollipdii@email.com        2022-Oct-01       4
kwoot.khtp@email.com          2022-Nov-04       2
imiti4282@email.com           2022-Nov-12       10
pmokh.midhpki95@email.com     2022-Nov-02       2
).ktigtpk-tgikkod@iclopd.com  2022-Dec-08       1
).ktigtpk-tgikkod@iclopd.com  2022-Dec-09       1
```

Comment: Please provide data samples from all used tables in the text format and describe the criterion of the new email.

Comment: The criterion of the new email is that if the email is created in the November and the same email is present in December then that email should not bet counted as the email created. The email created should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

First you table should be ordered by year+month (just sort by CreatedAt).
[image]
Formulas:

H2=YEAR(F2)*100+MONTH(F2), fill down

I2=COUNTIF($E$1:E1;E2), fill down

M6=DCOUNT($E$1:$I$11;3;$K$5:$L$6)

Enter to K6 the year/month you are interested in.

Use the pivot table to create a report.
[image]